# Windows Phone 8 - Streaming a Podcast MP3 file

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, stream, podcast

I'm creating an app that reads a single podcast feed (unique to the app) and shows the episode titles in a `LongListSelector`. I can obtain the MP3 URI for each episode by parsing the RSS file. I'd like to add functionality that, when the user taps an item in the list, the URI is passed to an audio streamer and played like a music file.

I saw a tutorial on [How to play background audio for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which points me to a project template for streaming audio.

I'm just wondering, is it still necessary to follow those steps and create a separate project, or is there a built-in API call in Windows Phone 8 that I can just pass my URI to and have it stream automatically?

Comment: Hello, have you found an answer to this?

Comment: @JakubHolovsky Unfortunately, no. Now that you mention it, though, I think I'll start a bounty.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb

Comment: @JakubHolovsky I believe so, will need to check when I get back to this. It's been on hold awhile

Comment: @miguelarcilla, Do you still not able to get answer? if not,what is your problem now?

Comment: Yes, you still have to make a seperate Project that acts as Background Player. The Question is, why is this a problem for you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,if you need to use BackgroungAudioPlayer, it is necessary to create another project for AudioPlayer and add reference of it to your project.

Through MediaPlayer you can play files from medialibrary or IsolatedStorage.

So,for you it is necessary to follow those steps.Hope this helps.

Comment: Was my answer useful? If not what else you need to ask?

Comment: Sorry vits, it was just my remark - unfortunately incorrect - I've mistaken your `MediaPlayer` with `MediaElement`, which in fact cannot play in background.

Comment: yes,both BackgroundAudioPlayer and MediaPlayer can run in background,although you can not disable controls of MediaPlayer  (play/pause) screen that comes in notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the media element tag from the Windows Phone 8 Toolbox:

You should be able to achieve this without any difficulty, But it will not run in the background.