# Windows Phone 8 Audiotrack Error - Why?

Tags: c#, exception, audio, windows-phone-8, audiotrack

I'm trying to play an internet audio file in my app, but i'm having problems with large files. The code:

```
 var track = 
 new AudioTrack(
        new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute),
        "Podcast",
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        null);
```

The "uri" var (string) when debugging contains a valid url: uri = "http://www.msftinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/podcast_1.mp3", the AudioTrack object creates but there is no audio when play(). The error into the AudioTrack object:

[image: AudioTrack Error]

"Duration = 'track.Duration' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'"

{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.Interop.IAudioTrack.get_Duration()
   at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioTrack.get_Duration()}

Why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string url = "http://www.msftinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/podcast_1.mp3";
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(new Uri(url), null, null, null, null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.None);
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = audioTrack;
```

This itself works for me.

Also check my answer here:

[Windows Phone 8 - Streaming a Podcast MP3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036527/windows-phone-8-streaming-a-podcast-mp3-file/23534055#23534055)

Just for info : For Streaming in windows 8.1 you have new API BackgroundAudioStreamer.

Comment: Wow thanks, it seems that is neccesary to pass the param EnabledPlayerControls.None. If Null it will not play.

Comment: yes,it should know whether to show player controls or not :D...cheers